# Emacs Slime - Comma doesn't work

Tags: emacs, common-lisp, sbcl, slime

I have emacs 24.5.1 on windows with slime installed.  I am using sbcl for lisp.  When I open up slime, it works, but whenever I try to use comma to invoke a command, it just enters a comma.  I can't get to the slime command menu.  Is there any other way to get to the command menu besides comma?

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution.
When going to the slime git website, they said you should include this in your initialization file

(setq slime-contribs '(slime-fancy))

It works after adding that to init.el (equivalent of .emacs)